# Physical Memory Utilization in Solaris

Tags: memory-management, solaris

From previous questions on the topic I've found two ways of getting the memory usage:

1. `echo "::memstat" | mdb -k`
2. `a=$(/usr/sbin/prtconf | /usr/bin/awk '/Memory/ {print $3*1024}'); vmstat 1 2 | tail -1 | awk "{print 100 - (\$5 / $a) * 100}"`

I opted for the first one since I'd rather rely on existing tooling rather than calculating it on my own. However, on some systems the output of "::memstat" is formatted slightly differently than others (Header starts with "Usage Type/Subtype" instead of "Page Summary" etc). This is a bit of an issue since I'm parsing it in code.

I could just fix the parser to deal with both variants, hoping that there are no other variants in hiding.

Could anyone suggest a better way that won't be as brittle?

Comment: Found #1 here: https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-to-check-and-analyze-memory-usage-in-solaris/
and #2 here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/472044/memory-utilization-in-percentage-in-sun-solaris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually found the answer in the [Solaris documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E29034/sysconf-3c.html).

sysconf offers _SC_PHYS_PAGES for total pages and _SC_AVPHYS_PAGES for available pages